# where to find the M/R configuration file and update it

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

our Hadoop cluster shows the job tracker process eat up memory gradually that we have to restart the cluster every week. I searched around for the possible solution for this. one of the post mentioned to decrease 'mapred.jobtracker.completeuserjobs.maximum' to 5, so i checked mapred-site.xml under /hadoop-install/conf directory on name node and found there are two entries for that parameter, one set it to 30, the other set it to 5, when i goto any of the data node and check mapred-site.xml, i don't find the setting for that parameter at all.  however when I checked running job on M/R administration page and checked their job file, it showed that parameters set to 100. I'm really confused where does this parameter is set. and if i updated it, do i need to restart the cluster?  we are running apache Hadoop 1.2.1 on google cloud

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop does not automatically copy the configuration files from your driver machine to all of the cluster machines You need to do that via scp and/or rsync or preferably an automated deployment tool like chef, ansible, puppet, etc.

As far as the individual job parameters: you can actually set them on per-job basis by using -D:

```
<path to jar>/myHadoopJobJar.jar  -Dmapred.jobtracker.completeuserjobs.maximum=5
```